# Django render loop output to the template

Tags: python, django

I have a function in my view that crops thousands of images in background:

```
def run_task(request):
    initialize()
    return render(request,'home/index.html')

def postpone(function):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        t = Thread(target = function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    return decorator


@postpone
def initialize():

    allimages = []
    number = 0

    if not os.path.exists('thumbnails'):
        os.makedirs('thumbnails')

    path = '/Users/shoaibrafa/Data/*.jpg'

    for image in glob.glob(path):
        print(image,"=====",number)
        im = Image.open(image)
        im.thumbnail((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im.save("thumbnails/" + os.path.basename(image), "JPEG")
        number = number + 1
```

my problem is how can I show in the template (index.html) how many images are processed so far! or simply how can I send the 'number' value to my template in each iteration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/

Comment: Thanks for reply! i do not want to use celery the way i have implemented the postpone method works perfect!